# Google cli - where to ask questions?

Tags: command-line-interface, googlecl

I'm trying to use the Google CLI (e.g. 'google calendar "...") It used to work poorly and now fails with an error diagnostic. Searching for "google calendar" is actually less useless than searching for "Evolution email."

I wish people would think about searchability when naming programs. /rant

Is there a forum or newsgroup somewhere that I can post questions?

And if there's an expert here, After I open a browser and authorize, the program produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/google", line 839, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/google", line 825, in main
    run_once(options, args)
  File "/usr/bin/google", line 605, in run_once
    authenticated = authenticate(auth_manager, options, config, section_header)
  File "/usr/bin/google", line 119, in authenticate
    valid_token = auth_manager.retrieve_access_token(display_name, browser)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/googlecl/authentication.py", line 180, in retrieve_access_token
    self.client.current_token)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/googlecl/authentication.py", line 255, in write_access_token
    with open(self.tokens_path, 'wb') as tokens_file:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hbarta/.local/share/googlecl/access_tok_crbmwweb'
```

many thanks,
hank

Comment: Google Mail Help Forum:  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/label?lid=482eb9865868a1b9&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is to create the missing directory: `mkdir ~/.local/share/googlecl`

The official site for Google CL is http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/ - and the issue you mention is described and tracked [here](http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/issues/detail?id=352&can=1&q=.local%2Fshare&colspec=ID%20Type%20Stars%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary)